# Connect to an gitlab user

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, error-handling, gitlab

i would like to connect to a user in my gitlab server.

i connect to the gitlab server:

```
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('http://10.0.0.120')
print(gl.users.list())
```

the connect to the server not getting me any errors but after adding the line:

```
print(gl.users.list())
```

i get this error:

```
raise error(e.error_message, e.response_code, e.response_body) from e
gitlab.exceptions.GitlabListError: 403: 403 Forbidden - Not authorized to access /api/v4/users
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we use the terminal to connect to gitlab users. You can follow the following steps:

1. Call the terminal with **"ctrl+~"** in vscode
2. Use command `git init`
3. Configure user name and mailbox:

   git config --global user.name “user.name"

   git config --global user.email "user.email"